# Inverse Blocked matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a invertible matrix P which is constructed by:

$\mathbf{P} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{R_z} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A} \\
\mathbf{0}   & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{C} \\
\mathbf{A}^T & \mathbf{C}^T & \mathbf{0} \\  
\end{bmatrix}$

Where, $\mathbf{R_z}$ is a square and invertible matrix and $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are rectangular matrix with full rank. I want to find a expression for $\mathbf{P}^{-1}$, so I tried finding a matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such as:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{B_1}' & \mathbf{B_2}' & \mathbf{B_3}' \\
\mathbf{B_4}' & \mathbf{B_5}' & \mathbf{B_6}' \\
\mathbf{B_7}' & \mathbf{B_8}' & \mathbf{B_9}' \\  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{R_z} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A} \\
\mathbf{0}   & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{C} \\
\mathbf{A}^T & \mathbf{C}^T & \mathbf{0} \\  
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{I}   & \mathbf{0}  & \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{0}   & \mathbf{I}  & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0}   & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$

Writting the equations, we have:

$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{B_1}'\mathbf{R_z} + \mathbf{B_3}'\mathbf{A}^T = \mathbf{I} \\
\mathbf{B_3}'\mathbf{C}^T = \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{B_1}'\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B_2}'\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{B_4}'\mathbf{R_z} + \mathbf{B_6}'\mathbf{A}^T = \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{B_6}'\mathbf{C}^T = \mathbf{I} \\
\mathbf{B_4}'\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B_5}'\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{B_7}'\mathbf{R_z} + \mathbf{B_9}'\mathbf{A}^T = \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{B_9}'\mathbf{C}^T = \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{B_7}'\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B_8}'\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{I} \\
\end{cases}
$

Solving this, we have:

$
\mathbf{B}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{R_z}^{-1}  & - \mathbf{R_z}^{-1} \mathbf{A}   \left(  \mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{C}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{C}^T   & \mathbf{0} \\
-  \left(  \mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^T\right)^{-1}  \mathbf{C} \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{R_z}^{-1} &  \left(  \mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^T\right)^{-1}  \mathbf{C} \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{R_z}^{-1} \mathbf{A}  \left(  \mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{C}\right)^{-1}  \mathbf{C}^T  & \left(  \mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^T\right)^{-1}  \mathbf{C} \\
\mathbf{0} & \left(  \mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{C} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{C}^T & \mathbf{0}  \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$

The problem is that $\left(  \mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{C} \right)$ and $\left(  \mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^T\right)$ are not $\underline{both}$ invertible.

What am I doing wrong? The matrix is invertible, but I can't find a expression for it.

Comment: It is not contradictory. It just means you cannot operate by using this $3 \times 3$ block splitting. Turn to a $2 \times 2$ block splitting, the upper left block being $R_Z$.

Comment: I tried, but it falls on the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to find a matrix $\alpha$ that:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{R_z} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A} \\
\mathbf{0}   & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{C} \\
\mathbf{A}^T & \mathbf{C}^T & \mathbf{0} \\  
\end{bmatrix}
^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A} \\
\mathbf{0}   & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{C} \\
\mathbf{A}^T & \mathbf{C}^T & \mathbf{0} \\  
\end{bmatrix}
^{-1}
\alpha
$